# if $p+q+r=0$ then $A^2- 4B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given: $A = \dfrac{(p^2+q^2+r^2)^2}{p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2}$ and $B=\dfrac{q^2-pr}{p^2+q^2+r^2}$.

If $p+q+r=0$, then $A^2-4B=$

I tried to expand the numerator of $A$, but it gets complicated. I tried to subtitute $A$ and $B$ to the question, it gets complicated too.

Comment: Do not unnecessarily expand. The goal of this question is qet you to express both equations of $A$ and $B$ in terms of $p + q + r$. This is because it will simplify the equation, since substituting $p + q + r = 0$, would cause some of the terms to vanish. Ie. $$p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = (p + q + r)^2 + 2(pq + qp + pr) = 0 + 2(pq + qp + pr) = 2(pq + qp + pr)$$

Comment: One can use $r=-(p+q)$ and calculate both $A$ and $B$

Comment: @Dstarred I think you mean $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = (p + q + r)^2 - 2(pq + qp + pr)=-2(pq+qp+pr)$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yep, my bad. I cannot edit now, so I will just leave it there.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X=p^2+q^2+r^2$ and $Y=pq+qr+pr$

Then we know that, $$(pq+qr+pr)^2=p^2r^2+p^2q^2+r^2q^2+2pqr(p+q+r)$$
$$\implies (pq+qr+pr)^2=p^2r^2+p^2q^2+r^2q^2$$ as $p+q+r=0$

So we can say that $$A = \dfrac{(p^2+q^2+r^2)^2}{(pq+qr+pr)^2}
$$ or $$A=\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)^2$$
Also we know that $$(p+q+r)^2=X+2Y$$ so from here we conclude that $\frac{X}{Y}=-2$ or $$\boxed{\color{red}{A=4}}$$

---

As $p+q+r=0$ we can see that $p+r=-q$ or $p^2+r^2+2pr=q^2$

Substitute this value of $q^2$ in $B$ and simplify
$$B=\dfrac{q^2-pr}{p^2+q^2+r^2}
$$
$$\implies B=\dfrac{p^2+r^2+2pr-pr}{p^2+p^2+r^2+2pr+r^2}
$$
$$\implies B=\dfrac{p^2+r^2+pr}{2(p^2+r^2+pr)}
$$
$$\implies \boxed{\color{blue}{B=\frac12}}$$

---

So $$ \boxed{\color{green}{A^2-4B=14}}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those where the outcome is indicated to be independent of the specific choice of $p,q,r,$  as long as the sum is correct

Take $p=1,q=0,r=-1$

$A$   comes out $4,$   $B$ comes out $\frac{1}{2}$